# Data not saving to an array

Tags: php, arrays

Why in the code below is all my data not saving to the array?

I can do a var_dump within the foreach and that will show me what I want however `$cbContent` is only returning the first object?

**Code:**

```
$cbContent = array();

foreach ($guests as $guest)
{
  $cbContent[] = array(
   'FirstName' => $guest['FirstName'],
   'LastName' => $guest['LastName'],
   'Email' => $guest['email'],
   'Country' => $guest['country'],
   '_CheckIn' => $guest['check-in_date'],
   '_CheckOut' => $guest['check-out_date'],
  );
}
var_dump($cbContent); exit();
```

**COD Response:**

```
Array
(
    [FirstName] => Test
    [LastName] => Test
    [Email] => 
    [Country] => New Zealand
    [_CheckIn] => 2017-04-25
    [_CheckOut] => 2017-04-27
    [0] => Array
        (
            [FirstName] => Test 1
            [LastName] => Test 2
            [Email] => 
            [Country] => United Kingdom
            [_CheckIn] => 2017-04-25
            [_CheckOut] => 2017-04-26
        )
```

Comment: `var_dump()` guests. Perhaps it's your guest array that is incorrect?

Comment: try with `print_r($cbContent);`

Comment: @FrankerZ Its not thats the thing that works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED:
Try to use:

[array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php);

example:

```
$cbContent = array();
foreach ($guests as $guest)
{
    $data = array(
       'FirstName' => $guest['FirstName'],
       'LastName' => $guest['LastName'],
       'Email' => $guest['email'],
       'Country' => $guest['country'],
       '_CheckIn' => $guest['check-in_date'],
       '_CheckOut' => $guest['check-out_date'],
      );
    if(empty($cbContent)){
        $cbContent = $data;
    } else {
        array_push($cbContent, $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: why down vote? i'm just trying to suggest.... is there anything wrong? does the array_push doesn't saving data? @Jess McKenzie is asking only about data not saving to an array so in any case he wants to save the data to array thats why we can use array_push.  Please reply to my comment for this clarification and please before doing any downvotes just think it first. You're not helping by doing that.

Comment: Thanks,  I have updated what that gave me in my question.  Should it not all be within the array?

Comment: Your welcome. Can you update your question and post the data of array "$guests". It seems the problem is in the array itself.